# Recaptcha: Is it possible to integrate Google Recaptcha on all pages instead of forms alone

Tags: recaptcha

I have seen several websites showing google recaptcha when opening their pages in Tor browser or vpn connection, is it possible to integrate invisible recaptcha on all pages in website which is running in PHP, so that bots or other malicious traffic can be blocked with the recaptcha. I have searched recpatcha documentation here : https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro

But there is no clear steps described to add the recapthca on pages. Any suggestions or documentation to run invisible captcha on webpages instead of forms is appreciated.